# Set selected segment on UISegmentedControl created in IB

Tags: uisegmentedcontrol

I have created 5 UISegmetedControls in IB with 3 segments each. I save the selected segment in an NSArray. The problem is when I would like to load the view again with the same segments selected as the user choosed before. How do I access the UISegmentedControl? Each control has a different tag value. Do I have to create them programatically?

EDIT
Found a solution:
I created an IBOutlet for each control. It works but there might be a better solution.

```
@interface UISegmentedControlViewController : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *Segment1;
IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *Segment2;
IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *Segment3;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also create an IBOUtletCollection (and have all SegmentedControls be a member of that collection). This is useful if they perform more or less the same function, while still being able to distinguish them via their tag.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `NSArray` stores the indexes of the selected segments.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

    Segment1.selectedSegmentIndex = [[array objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];// First index  (0,1 or 2)
    Segment2.selectedSegmentIndex = [[array objectAtIndex:1] integerValue];// Second index (0,1 or 2)
    Segment3.selectedSegmentIndex = [[array objectAtIndex:2] integerValue];// Third index  (0,1 or 2)
}
```